# probability problem with CD music

Tags: probability

There is a shelf containing many type of CD music: 8 rock music, 2 classic music and 11 pop music.
So i'm going to hear 1 CD per day for a whole month. What is the chance of hearing classic music less than 3 times in the month.

So i understand that the probability to hear classic music per day is 2/21 but i couldn't figure out how to manage the month part and the less than 3 times part.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since there 19 other possibilities to listen, probability of not listening to classical music in a typical day is $\frac{19}{21}$ . Assuming a month is 30 days,  the probability of never listening classical music in a month is $(\frac{19}{21})^{30}$ because each day is indepedent of the other days. Similarly you can find the probabilities for listening classical music once and twice month and add all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you select CDs at random with replacement for $n = 30$ days, with probability $p = 2/21$ of getting a classical-music CD on any one day,
the number $X$ of days on which you get classical music is 
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 30,\, p = 2/21)$ and for *less than or equal* to three times in a month the probability is: 
$$P(X \le 3) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + P(X = 2) + P(X = 3),$$
where $P(X = k) = {30 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 30.$

Because you have not shown any progress toward a solution I have no clue
how you are supposed to evaluate the displayed probability: (a) by using the
formula four times, (b) with a normal approximation to the binomial distribution, (c) with a Poisson approximation, or (d) by using software. In R statistical software
the exact binomial computation is as below, a normal approximation gives about 0.66, and
a Poisson approximation gives about 0.68:

```
pbinom(3, 30, 2/21)
## 0.6810339
```

In the plot below, binomial probabilities are represented by bars and Poisson
probabilities by the centers of small circles. The density function of the
"best-fitting" normal curve is also shown. The probability of interest (in my version of the problem) is to
the left of the vertical dotted line.

[image]

I hope this gives you some idea how to find $P(X < 3).$

Answer (score 0):

To find the probability of hearing classic music less than 3 times in the month, we can break it down into two cases:

Hearing classic music 0 times in the month.
Hearing classic music 1 time in the month.
Let's calculate the probability for each case:

Case 1: Hearing classic music 0 times in the month

The probability of not hearing classic music on any given day is 19/21 (since there are 19 non-classic CDs out of 21 total). Since you're doing this for a whole month (30 days), the probability of not hearing classic music on all 30 days is:

$$(\frac{19}{21})^{30}$$

Case 2: Hearing classic music 1 time in the month

The probability of hearing classic music on any given day is 2/21. The probability of not hearing classic music on any other day is 19/21. So, to have exactly one day with classic music and 29 days without, we have to consider all possible combinations. There are 30 ways you can choose one day to hear classic music. So, the probability of hearing classic music exactly once in the month is:

$$30\cdot \frac{2}{21} \cdot (\frac{19}{21})^29$$

Now, to find the total probability of hearing classic music less than 3 times in the month, you simply add the probabilities of these two cases together:

$$\text{Total Probability = Probability of Case 1 + Probability of Case 2}$$
$$ = (\frac{19}{21})^{30}+ 30\cdot \frac{2}{21} \cdot (\frac{19}{21})^29$$

Calculating this will give you the chance of hearing classic music less than 3 times in the month.